# EmberJS registerHelper to dynamically render a template in Ember 1.8

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to dynamically render a template, like this:

```
{{#each layout in layouts}}
   {{render layout.get('type') layout}}
{{/each}}
```

The problem is that render doesn't expect a variable as its first arguments, so in the older EmberJS-versions, a workaround was possible by registering a helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('render_layout', 
  function(callingContext, layout, options) {
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.render.call(callingContext, 
                layout.get('type'), 'layout', options);
});
```

and in the template:

```
{{#each layout in layouts}}
     {{render_layout this layout}}
{{/each}}
```

Unfortunately the thing doesn't work in newer ember versions. 
`Ember.Handlebars.helpers.render.call` expects 3 arguments but I can not get them right. Any ideas?
I've tried:
    `(this, layout.get('type'), options)`

and in the template:

```
{{#each layout in layouts}}
     {{render_layout layout}}
{{/each}}
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushChildView' of null`

... and many others.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd start off by looking at the Ember/HBS source for the `{{render}}` helper and see how it might be tweaked to do what you want.

Comment: I already did and tbh (this, layout.get('type'), options) seems to be the correct approach, but apparently I've missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components allow you to specify `layoutName`. And you can dynamically compute the layout name based on a parameter passed into the component.

```
App.XRenderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: "",
  layoutName: function(){
    return this.get('displayLayout.type'); 
  }.property('displayLayout'),
});
```

Then you can just do

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    {{#each layout in model}}
      {{ x-render displayLayout=layout }}
    {{/each}}   
  </script>
```

See working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bakipa/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Way more flexible. Thanks.